# Qt Creator - move *.user settings file from project folder

Tags: qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator on Windows and Linux using the same project folder. The problem is Qt Creator created `CMakeLists.txt.user` (or `project_name.pro.user` for qmake projects) file in the project directory. Every time I switch OS, Qt Creator fails to load settings file and rewrites it with default settings, which is annoying. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it happens because your compiller preferences change with the OS, and there is no way to save your user file to be rewritten, unless you manually backup it.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question, when it is the same OS, or in fact it is on the same machine, but different folder.   I want every project paths to be relative to the project directory, while the tool-chain should be in absolute path.  Is there any way to do it easily?  Currently I just remove .pro.user and then manually add it back, by visually comparing each items in the Build (for build) and Run (for many sets of the running arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare environment variable QTC_USER_FILE_PATH

Comment: Thanks for your response -- which would be even better if you could please share an example of how to declare/use the env. variable.